# regular expression for full name

Tags: python, regex

I want my regex expression to encompass all types of full names.
ex: John F. Kennedy, J.F. Kennedy, John Kennedy, etc.

```
([A-Z][a-zA-Z]+)[ ]*(?:\s[^\s]+)?\s([A-Z][a-zA-Z]+)
```

I wrote this initially, but i noticed that J.F. Kennedy would not be included. I want all types of names to be found. 
Would appreciate it if someone could help me solve this, thank you! 
Also, is there a difference between `[ ]*` and `\s`?

Comment: Where do you find these names? If "in the wild", you won't get very far without a database to check the names against. A regex cannot figure out the difference between `New York` (not a person's name) and `John F. Kennedy`.

Comment: ``\s`` is any white space, also tabs and newlines

Comment: Before you start parsing names you should read [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/) .

Comment: What about `O'Connor` or `Jean-François`?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this regex: `/^([A-Z]([a-z]+|\.)\s*){2,3}$/`

It specifies that each part of the name must start with an uppercase letter followed by either a dot or lowercase letters, and there can be from 2 to 3 parts in a name.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/cfCquW/2

Comment: Idk why but it doesn't seem to work on mine which is really weird :( but still thank you so much for your help <3 this seems like a really clean code that i'll definitely use in my next project.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your definition of "name", the result may vary.

One possibility:

1. We have a capital letter at the beginning
2. It is followed by one period or any number of lower-case letters and a trailing space
3. 1) and 2) are followed by any number of white space and repeated at least once
4. We have one capital letter followed by one or more lower-case letters (the complete surname).

This example leads to the regex `(?:[A-Z](?:\.|[a-z]+ )\s*)+[A-Z][a-z]+`

If you want the surname to be abbreviated, leave the last part away.
If you want to allow `` '`- `` in the names, insert them.

Comment: Idk why but it doesn't seem to work on my code :( but still thank you so much for your help <3 i'll play around with it.